# java.sql.Date to joda time conversion

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jodatime

oracle sql:

```
select trunc( sysdate, 'Month') month
from dual
```

java:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = resultSet.getDate("month");
log.info(sqlDate);
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(sqlDate.getTime());
log.info(dateTime);
dateTime = dateTime.withMillisOfDay(0);
log.info(dateTime);
```

output:

2012-01-01

2012-01-01T **01**:00:00.000+07:00

2012-01-01T **00**:00:00.000+07:00

where did the extra hour?

Comment: i think this time zone problem, check with correct time zone?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `LocalDate.fromDateFields(date)` to interpret the SQL date as local (ignoring time-zone). You can then use methods on `LocalDate` to get a `DateTime` if necessary (although if your object really is "just a date" then `LocalDate` is the right object to use.

Comment: Just a note - I was dealing with `java.sql.Timestamp` and not `java.sql.Date`, so using `new DateTime(java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(someSqlDate));` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Default constructor uses system default constructor, and that might be causing issues with regards to DST. I found the [toDateMidnight](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#toDateMidnight%28%29) function really useful when trying to make sure I was actually at midnight.

Comment: What if time will not increase, and subtract?

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm not sure what you are referring to. `toDateMidngith` returns a `LocalDate` object, and it can only represent dates, not times. Is that the problem? If so, then it may not be what you're looking for. If `withMillisOfDay()` works for you then stick with it.

Comment: FYI, the Joda-Time team no longer recommends the "midnight"-related classes and methods. They added the method [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()) to the DateTime class instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code.

```
LocalDate issueDate = new LocalDate(new Date());
System.out.println(new java.sql.Date(issueDate.toDate().getTime()))
```